# Creating multiple WebSocket connections in nodejs in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Hi as in the title I wanna create multiple WebSocket clients in node, so I decided to create a class that would be managing a single connection and then creates an X instance of this class.
Here is my code

```
class CreateNewConnection {
  constructor () {
    this.ws = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org/', {
      origin: 'https://websocket.org'
    })
    this.ws.on('open', function open () {
      console.log('connected')
      this.ws.send(Date.now())
    })

    this.ws.on('close', function close () {
      console.log('disconnected')
    })

    this.ws.on('message', function incoming (data) {
      console.log(`Roundtrip time: ${Date.now() - data} ms`)

      setTimeout(function timeout () {
        this.ws.send(Date.now())
      }, 500)
    })
  }
}
```

I am getting an error

```
  this.ws.send(Date.now())


TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

Anybody have any ideas why this isn't working? P.S I am using ws library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call `send` method from *closure*. To abolish *closure* you have 2 ways:

1. You need to use *arrow functions* between class's constructor *closure* and your `send` method call:

   ```
   this.ws.on('message', (data) => {
       console.log(\`Roundtrip time: ${Date.now() - data} ms\`)
       setTimeout(() => {
           this.ws.send(Date.now())
       }, 500)
   })
   ```
2. You need to create variable which would refers to class this context:

   ```
   constructor () {
       var _this = this;
   // code code code    
   _this.ws.send(Date.now());
   ```

Here you can read about arrow functions:
https://javascript.info/arrow-functions-basics

And here about closures:
https://medium.com/@prashantramnyc/javascript-closures-simplified-d0d23fa06ba4

TL;DR

Your `this.ws.send(Date.now())` refers to timeout function `this` context, not to class this context.